# Poisson distribution, more occurrences in a period of time

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have a doubt about the following problem:

the number of visits is an aleatory variable that has a Poisson distribution with a rate of 2 visits per minute. We know that in 4 minutes there were 5 visits. What is the probability that more visits occurred in the first 2 minutes than in the las 2 minutes?

My thoughts:

$\lambda=2$ and $\lambda t=2\times 2=4$. We find the probabilities for the cases where of 3,4,or 5 visits in the first 2 minutes:

$P(first2minutes)=P(3,4)+P(4,4)+P(5,4)=0.547$

where $P(x,\lambda t)=\frac{(\lambda t)^xe^{-\lambda t}}{x!}$

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: By symmetry, this probability is also the probability that less visits occurred in the first 2 minutes than in the last 2 minutes. The total number of visits is odd hence there is no tie, thus the desired probability is 50%. This solution does not use the unconditional rate of the Poisson process.

Comment: If $\lambda$ was different the probability would also be 50%?

Comment: See previous comment. The value of lambda is not required hence if lambda = 2 or if lambda = 42 or if lambda = pi^2/9, the answer is still 50%.

Answer (score 2):

Let $B$ be the event there were $5$ visits in $4$ minutes. Let $A$ be the event there were more visits in the first $2$ minutes than in the last $2$. We want $\Pr(A|B)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

The number of visits in $4$ minutes has Poisson distribution parameter $8$. It follows that $\Pr(B)=e^{-8}\frac{8^5}{5!}$.

The event $A$ can happen in $3$ ways: (i) $3$ in the first $2$ minutes, and $2$ in the next $2$ minutes; (ii) $4$ and $1$; $5$ and $0$, The number of visits in $2$ minutes has Poisson distribution parameter $4$.

(i) The probability of $3$ and $2$ is $e^{-4}\frac{4^3}{3!}e^{-4}\frac{4^2}{2!}$. We can find similar expressions for the probabilities of (ii) and (iii). Add to find $\Pr(A\cap B)$.

**Remark:** There were some errors in the proposed solution. First, the problem is a conditional probability problem, and the computation did not take account of that. Second, the probabilities of $3$ and $2$, $4$ and $1$, and $5$ and $0$ were not calculated correctly, since the calculations did not take into account what happens in the second $2$ minute interval.

Comment: Thank you. Can the problem be solved using binomial distribution by finding the probabilities of the three cases and adding them?

Comment: Yes, it can. The *conditional distribution* of the number of events in the "first" period, given the total, **is** indeed binomial. That can be proved in a fair degree of generality, using a computation much like our specific calculation above. **If** a theorem of this kind has already been proved in your course, you could simply use it. But I suspect you are expected to do a computation much like the one I sketched in the answer. Or else note that by symmetry the conditional probability is $1/2$. But that would not help if we are dealing with sy intervals of $1$ minute and $3$ minutes.